# WiX Change property depending on Upgrade

Tags: wix, directory, preprocessor, upgrade

The installation path of some features in my product depends on some other products which are maybe installed.

E.g. if Product "X 2014" is installed then it should take the path "Y 2014".
E.g. if Product "H 2015" is installed then it should take the path "K 2015".

I tried it with a property, as default I set the value to "2014", if the condition is true then "2015".

```
<Property Id="YEAR" Value="2014" />
<SetProperty Id="YEAR" Value="2015" After="AppSearch">2015_EXISTS</SetProperty>
```

I used then this property in here:

```
<Directory Id="Company"
           Name="Company">
      <Directory Id="Something"
           Name="Hello [YEAR]">
      </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Put it does not use the value inside this variable, just literly the "[YEAR]" and this is not what I want.

I also found that I could use preprocessor variables, but I'm clearly not know how to use them on a condition.
The condition is made by:

```
!--    Product 2015 -->
<Upgrade Id="GUID">
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes"
                  Property="2015_EXISTS"
                  IncludeMinimum="no"
                    Maximum="999.999.999.999"/>
</Upgrade>
```

Could please somebody explain me how I could solve my issue?
A working code would be perfect!!

EDIT:
The workaround I have at the moment is:

```
<Directory Id="Company"
       Name="Company">
  <Directory Id="Something13"
       Name="Hello 2013">
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="Something14"
       Name="Hello 2014">
  </Directory>
```

But this is really ugly, think I have to extend this then for 2015, 2016 and so on... and the strucutre insinde these Directories are quiet deep and in every year the same structure.
I dont want to repeat myself so many times, it get's also really a mess looking at it.

Comment: This is not Standard Practice.  Use Burn to install the Packages that may or may not be installed then code your MSI, assuming that All Packages have been installed.  After doing so, use Install Conditions to Determine if the Package was installed.  If Install condition is True, Install in DirA.  If InstallCondition is False Install or Skip

Comment: Do you mean I should create a bootstrapper? In our case it is simple not possible for some reasons to create a bootstrapper.

Comment: Yes, I mean create a Bootstrapper using Burn, using Versions above WiX 3.6.  Why is this not possible??

Comment: We can not use an exe, because we NEED a msi. Also it is much time effort now, only for this little thing. In the meantime I have a workaround..

Comment: I'm glad you have a work around, and I hope you understand that a burn bundle can contain multiple MSI's, and the Exe just triggers a chain of multiple MSI's

Comment: AFAIK it's not actually possible to do what you're asking because the Directory elements are determined at compile time, not runtime when the properties are resolved. As I understand it, your requirement is to not have to remember to change the property within the WXS file each year with your product release. Do you version your MSI Wix package with the same version number?